# How bad is it to assemble the lulav on chag

Tags: halacha, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I know one ideally should not assemble the Lulav on the actual holiday yet there are many people who don't know how to do it and despite the printed instructions we (the L & E vendors) offer them, haven't put the thing together by the time they've come to schul.

Is it really a sin to assemble the lulav or is it just a chumra to refrain from doing so.

Comment: We always end up putting it together on Yomtov because we need to keep the aravot (and preferably haddasim too) in the fridge.

Comment: If by "assemble" you mean you attach the hadassim and aravot, it is not a "permanent" binding in fact you intend to remove them again before 24 hours to put the hadassim and aravot back in the fridge.. (at least I do)

Comment: The Gemara has a whole discussion about what kind of binding to do if you forgot to bind the lulav-hadas-arava properly (with a knot that can't be tied on Yom Tov) before Yom Tov. Obviously, we see you should bind it in that way before Yom Tov lechatchila, and if you forgot, then use the Gemara's suggestion of tying a bow-knot to bedieved bind them. cc @Scimonster